# I can connect to the database via SQL Server 2008, but can't connect via Node.js

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008, node.js

So, without any special stuff, I can connect to a remote SQL server via SQL Server 2008 (Server type: Database Engine, Authentication: SQL Server Authentication).

I take the same Server name and go into Node.js on my computer and use https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql as my mysql connector, and I get the following:

```
var mysql = require("mysql");

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
host:   "(server name)",
user:   "myusername",
password:   "mypassword",
database:   "mydb"
});

connection.connect();

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:892:19)
--------------------
at Handshake.Sequence (C:\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence
.js:15:20)
at new Handshake (C:\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Handshake.js:
9:12)
at Protocol.handshake (C:\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:42:50)

at Connection.connect (C:\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:73:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\server.js:12:12)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

Strangely enough, I try using the mysql command line, and I can't connect through that either:

```
C:\>mysql -h (IP)
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '(IP)' (10061)
```

I'm at a loss! I'm using Windows 7, and everything I can come up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, SQL Server and MySQL doesn't share anything but the SQL and some syntax. The protocol of the connection aren't the same. So the node-mysql package won't work for you.

You can find the SQL Server driver on [this MSND page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlphp/archive/2012/06/08/introducing-the-microsoft-driver-for-node-js-for-sql-server.aspx) with the explication on how to use it or directly on the [GitHub page](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/node-sqlserver) of the project.

Comment: Interesting. It won't let me do the node-gyp configure part. It's giving me the below error:

    gyp ERR! stack Error: Python executable "python" is v3.3.2, which is not supported by gyp.

Comment: It sounds like you need to downgrade Python to 2.7.x or something

Comment: Believe it or not, I was on the WAAY wrong path with my response to brnrd; he hit it right on the head!

So, I had to uninstall Node and reinstall it as version 0.8.9; doing this, and following brnrd's steps, fixed it!